# How to access multidimensional array item by id in Shopify Liquid

Tags: multidimensional-array, jekyll, liquid

I have a list of items generated from a CSL export to YAML in a Jekyll data file that looks like this:

```yaml
references:
- id: palazzo:2021vernacular
  accessed:
    - year: 2021
      month: 11
      day: 10
  author:
    - family: Palazzo
      given: Pedro P.
  citation-key: palazzo:2021vernacular
  container-title: Journal of Traditional Building, Architecture and Urbanism
  DOI: 10.51303/jtbau.vi2.524
  ISSN: 2660-583X
  issue: '2'
  issued:
    - year: 2021
      month: 11
      day: 10
  language: en
  page: 359-370
  source: traditionalarchitecturejournal.com
  title: 'Vernacular patterns in Portugal and Brazil: evolution and adaptations'
  type: article-journal
  URL: https://traditionalarchitecturejournal.com/index.php/home/article/view/524
```

I can successfully pull a single record by doing:

```
{% assign citekey = page.citekey %}
{% assign work = site.data.bibliography.references | where: "id", citekey %}
```

This gives me a multidimensional JSON array. How can I access individual items from this array?

Answer (score 2):

Since the top-level result is itself an array made up of a single object, the expected format `{{ work.title }}` won't do here. Instead, I have to use `{{ work[0].title }}`.